# Network interface is initialized but not up on inserting USB 3g dongle (Intel Edison)

Tags: networking, udev, network-interface, ifconfig

Upon inserting a USB 3G dongle, the network interface is created and initialized, but it is not up.

```
root@edison:~# ifconfig -a
enp0s17u1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

On performing below actions, everything works fine.

```
root@edison:~# ifconfig enp0s17u1 up

root@edison:~# udhcpc -i enp0s17u1
udhcpc (v1.22.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.8.100...
Lease of 192.168.8.100 obtained, lease time 86400
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 192.168.8.1
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 192.168.8.1

root@edison:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.197.142): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.197.142: seq=1 ttl=53 time=97.373 ms
```

> This behaviour is on Edison. But On my ubuntu PC, the moment I insert
>   the USB Modem everything seems to be working fine.

I tried to look around to check if there are any udev rules, or whether some configuration is done in network files, but could not find it.

> I would like to know how is it configured in Ubuntu that when a new network interface is detected, it is brought up immediately?

I would like to adapt the same way as in Ubuntu to Up the network 
right way.

---

### UDEV Approach :

The following Udev approach is working for me. But i would like to use it only as the last resort.

```
root@edison:/etc/udev/rules.d# cat 40-huaweimodem.rules 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="14db", RUN+="/sbin/ifconfig enp0s17u1 up"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="14db", RUN+="/sbin/udhcpc -i enp0s17u1"
```

Comment: Are you using latest software on it (https://github.com/edison-fw/) or stuck with a stock image?